# Package ipython is not available I am using ubuntu 20.04.2LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python, dpkg

**I want to install ns3.33 simulator on my ubuntu 20.04.2LTS and when I run the command:**

apt-get install python-pygraphviz python-kiwi python-pygoocanvas libgoocanvas-dev ipython

**I have these errors:**

**Package ipython is not available,** but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package python-pygraphviz
E: Unable to locate package python-kiwi E: Unable to locate package python-pygoocanvas
E: Unable to locate package libgoocanvas-dev
E: Package 'ipython' has no installation candidate

**I have tried these commands, but the same problem:**

sudo apt update sudo apt install python-pip python3-pip

sudo -H pip install ipython sudo -H pip3 install ipython

**How to solve this ?**

Comment: ipython binary packages are available in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. They were dropped before 20.04 and are no longer available for newer releases.

Comment: So, what should I do ?

Comment: Install 18.04 since it is a LTS supported version and have at it for the next just over two years. Or find a version that works with modern software.

Comment: `ipython` is no longer available in the repository. Instead, `ipython3` should be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install it from the [GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/releases) it should work with 20.04.

Go to https://github.com/ipython/ipython/releases and download the **Source Code (tar.gz)** file.

Extract the contents:

```
tar zxvf ipython-7.18.1.tar.gz
```

Enter the newly created directory:

```
cd ipython-7.18.1/
```

Then use pip3 to install it:

```
pip3 install .
```

*Don't forget to add the `.` at the end of the command meaning to install from here.*

Hope this helps!